# Error when I run bundle exec in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I run `bundle exec rake test` it comes up with an error in the terminal. It can't seem to get passed this step

```
# Running:

.......EEE.......

Finished in 0.420936s, 40.3862 runs/s, 61.7672 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help:
NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationController::TestCase
    app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'


  2) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationController::TestCase
    app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'


  3) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about:
NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationController::TestCase
    app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

17 runs, 26 assertions, 0 failures, 3 errors, 0 skips
```

I tried fixing the problem to the code but have not come up with a solution.

```
class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get :help
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get :about
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line of you test code should be:

```
class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
```

It's ActionController - not ApplicationController.